Platform-agnostic, determine if a file is sparse
I am trying to determine if a given file is a sparse file. I know there is a way to check using the windows native API, and that unix-based systems have the stat command to get numbers for logical size vs actual blocks allocated. However, my project is trying not to use native code or run extra processes. Is there anything available in Java to determine if a file is sparse?
My initial attempt with ChatGPT came up with this:
public static boolean isSparseFile(Path path) throws IOException {
    // Get the logical size of the file
    long logicalSize = Files.size(path);
        
    // Read the file to calculate the actual size
    long actualSize = 0;
    try (var stream = Files.newInputStream(path)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; // Read in chunks
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) {
                if (buffer[i] != 0) {
                    actualSize += bytesRead; // Count only non-zero bytes
                    break; // We only need to count once per chunk
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // If the actual size is significantly less than the logical size, it's sparse
    return actualSize < logicalSize;
}

But this method seems suspect. It looks like will only determine a file to be "sparse" if there's a chunk-aligned section of 4096 zero bytes, and will otherwise just read the whole size of the file (in which case, why not break on the first zero block found when bytesRead != -1?). This runs the risk of a file being sparse with chunks less than 4096, or with a zero chunk larger than 4096 that straddles a chunk border. Additionally, I can't find any code online that corroborates this method. It's also entirely possible that a file with empty space has not been sparse-ified by the file system, and has blocks allocated for those empty spaces anyway. This method would still declare that file to be sparse.

Probably not possible in pure Java.

The ChatGPT code is counting blocks of zeros.  This doesn't tell you if the file has been (as you put it) "sparsified" by the OS.  AFAIK, there isn't a way to do it in Pure Java.
